# Expanding macros in autoload form

Tags: emacs, macros, autoload

How can I have autoload.el expand macros in `;;;###autoload` forms?  The normal `make-autoload` function appears to do so only for a selection of recognized forms, but say I want to have the following expand `my-def` properly,

```
(defmacro my-def (name args &rest body)
  `(progn
     (defalias ',name ,args ,@body)
     #',name))

;;;###autoload
(add-hook 'some-hook (my-def my-hook () ()))
```

What is the appropriate way to tell the autoload to expand  here?  Is there a reason not all forms are expanded with `macroexpand`, eg. a performance hit or something?

Update: It seems I could advise `make-autoload`, but I don't know if this could cause problems in general, eg.

```
(advice-add 'make-autoload :around
            (lambda (orig-fn form file &optional exp)
              (let ((new-form (macroexpand-all form)))
                (apply orig-fn
                       (list new-form file
                             (not (equal new-form form)))))))
```